# Make rectangles different colors in for loop

Tags: java, swing, draw

What I want to happen is the user choose the color that they want to make the rectangle. They can draw as many rectangles as they want with that color, but when they choose a new color, the first rectangles keep that color and the new ones use the new color.

```
    for(Point i : points)
    {
        g.setColor(color);
        int newX = (i.x/15)*15;
        int newY = (i.y/15)*15;
        g.fillRect(newX, newY, 15, 15);   
    }
```

That's the code I have so far, but each time the user chooses a new color, it makes all of the old rectangles that color too. How could I make it so the old rectangles are the old color and the new ones are the new color?

Comment: You need to create a custom class that holds information such as rectangle size/position and colour. Then when you draw each "object" in your list, you use the colour that is defined for that particular instance

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two solutions to this problem.